# Mapping data object with a type field to specific React Components with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have content in a (tree) structure of nodes, where each node has a type

```js
type NodeType = "text" | "image";

interface Node<T extends NodeType> {
  type: T;
}
```

To keep things simple, let's assume the contents we get ist not a tree but an array of nodes with different types:

```js
type Content = Nodes[NodeType][];

const content: Content = [{ type: "text" }, { type: "image" }];
```

Now I would like to iterate over this content and render a different `ReactComponent` depending in the `type` of the `Node`:

```js
function App() {
  const contents: Nodes[NodeType][] = [{ type: "text" }, { type: "image" }];
  return (
    <div>
      {contents.map((node) => {
        const Component = getComponent(node);
        return <Component node={node} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have big problems with implementing the `getComponent` function

```js
function getComponent<N extends Node>(node: N): React.FC<{ node: N }>;
```

I cannot get `TypeScript` to properly map `Node`s of different types to `FC`s that accept those `Node`s.

So what I hope to achieve is to get a function that will accept either a `text` or `image` node and return an `FC` that will accept that `node` as prop, so

```js
getComponent(node: Node<"text">): React.FC<{ node: Node<"text">}>;
getComponent(node: Node<"image">): React.FC<{ node: Node<"image">}>;
```

I have created a **CodeSandbox with my implementation here**

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-silence-90glv?file=/src/App.tsx

I will still copy and paste this here

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";

type NodeType = "text" | "image";

interface Node<T extends NodeType> {
  type: T;
}

type Nodes = {
  [T in NodeType]: Node<T>;
};

type Components = {
  [T in NodeType]: NodeFC<T>;
};

type NodeFC<T extends NodeType> = (props: { node: Nodes[T] }) => ReactElement;

const components: Components = {
  text: ({ node }) => <pre>{node.type}</pre>,
  image: ({ node }) => <pre>{node.type}</pre>
};

function getComponent<N extends Node<NodeType>>(
  node: N
): N extends Node<infer T> ? NodeFC<T> : never {
  return components[node.type];
  //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this does not work
}

const Content = (props: { node: Node<NodeType> }) => {
  const Component = getComponent(props.node);
  return <Component node={props.node} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const contents: Nodes[NodeType][] = [{ type: "text" }, { type: "image" }];
  return (
    <div>
      {contents.map((node) => (
        <Content node={node} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Line 27` throws the following Error

```js
return components[node.type];
```

> ```
> Type 'NodeFC<"text"> | NodeFC<"image">' is not assignable to type 'N extends Node<infer T> ? NodeFC<T> : never'.
>   Type 'NodeFC<"text">' is not assignable to type 'N extends Node<infer T> ? NodeFC<T> : never'.ts(2322)
> ```

I have tried many implementations, but I still cannot map `Node`s that have a specific `type`, to a specific `React Component` that will accept that `Node` as `Prop.`

Answer (score 0):

A user on Twitter solved the Problem:

https://twitter.com/mediaquery/status/1316375077735337989

Here is a diff of his changes:

https://www.diffchecker.com/uGdtWP3I

[image]

and the complete code on CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-framework-mwo7b?file=/src/App.tsx

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";

type NodeType = "text" | "image";

interface Node<T extends NodeType> {
  type: T;
}

type Nodes = {
  [T in NodeType]: Node<T>;
};

type Components<T extends NodeType> = {
  [key in T]: NodeFC<T>;
};

type NodeFC<T extends NodeType> = (props: { node: Nodes[T] }) => ReactElement;

const components: Components<NodeType> = {
  text: ({ node }) => <pre>{node.type}</pre>,
  image: ({ node }) => <pre>{node.type}</pre>
};

function getComponent<N extends Node<NodeType>>(
  node: N
): NodeFC<N['type']> {
  return components[node.type];
}

const Content = (props: { node: Node<NodeType> }) => {
  const Component = getComponent(props.node);
  return <Component node={props.node} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const contents: Nodes[NodeType][] = [{ type: "text" }, { type: "image" }];
  return (
    <div>
      {contents.map((node) => (
        <Content node={node} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```